# Chaining template handlers in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

Somehow I was under the impression that naming views like this was possible:

`show.js.custom.coffee`

Suppose I have both handlers working properly, and both `show.js.custom` and `show.js.coffee` work fine, but when I put both extensions together, Rails balks with (edited for brevity):

`Missing template show with {:handlers=>[:custom, :coffee], :formats=>[:js]}...`

So if this is at all possible, what is it I need to do to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes this would be nice. much like sprockets and its preprocessing feature.  i always want to parse ajax request views with view.js.coffee.haml.  i have made it work with help from coffeebeans

https://github.com/markbates/coffeebeans

perhaps you could manipulate it to what you need to do as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use haml in js.coffee templates by using the code from this [blog post](http://rubyandrails.posterous.com/rails-jscoffeehaml-templates) I wrote. And manipulate it for different types, just as brewster suggests.